# How will a change be invoked in the Room database to update the UI?

Tags: android, database, user-interface, android-room

I am new to Room in Android. I was looking at this image:
[image]

...in [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/building-an-android-app-using-android-architecture-components-room-viewmodel-and-livedata-702a0af899ae) and I got a little confused.

Based on my understanding of this image,

the Repository listens to changes in the Room Database, the View Model listen's to the repository, and the UI controller listens to the View Model.

As a result, when there's a change in the Room database, the UI will be refreshed.

What I don't understand is--**how will there ever be a change in the database itself**?

In an app, doesn't the change occur in the UI(for instance, the user adds a note in a to-do-list app), which should then notify the ***database***? Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think only the UI can change the database? If you're syncing to a server, then it would be your background sync that would be updating the database. You're writing the code, so you'd be the one to control who is writing into the database, right?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Good point. But why would I want to do that to change the UI?

Comment: It could be a list that is shown to the user and should be updated once the database is changed, for instance Exchange Rates

Comment: But what if we wanted the change the database when the UI changed? How would that work with room? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments above it is up to your implementation. Information can be updated outside of what your UI can do. You can create a user with your UI, but your UI doesn't dictate when the User is online, that is dictated by an outside source of information which could be represented in your database, and through that chain is then represented in your UI.

Comment: But what if we wanted the change the database when the UI changed? How would that work with room? Thanks.

Comment: Give me an example what would change in your UI that you would also want to represent in the database?

Comment: Like in a note app, they edit their note(UI), and we want to save the updated note in the database.

Comment: That would be a basic update, You give your Room `NoteDao` the updated `Note` Entity for an `@Update` operation.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you would just manually update the database instead of relying on the observer/subscriber pattern?

Comment: observer/subscriber pattern would be used to update your UI to reflect the database.

Comment: Yes, so in this case we wouldn't be using that, but rather manually updating our database, right(since we're updating the UI to reflect on the database)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233059/discussion-between-codingchap-and-avalerio).